# Can I omit "that" in the following sentences?

Tags: word-usage

Can I omit "that" in the following sentences?

1: It was such a terrible experience that I will never forget it.

2: It is such nice weather that I would like to go to the beach.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You certainly may. Check the question linked above; if you have a question it does not answer, edit your question to tell us what you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you very much!Can I omit "that" in the following sentences? 1:The weather is such that we can only stay in air-conditioned places. 2:The difference is such that all will perceive it.

Comment: @April You could ask a new question about omitting ***that*** in ***such that***.